# Определение и округление целого числа

Tags: javascript, jquery

Простая на первый взгляд задачка, никак не поддается решению. Необходимо округлить целое число, например, имея цифру в 12445, округлить до 12400. А цифру 12563, превратить в 12600.

При обычном раскладе, имея только цифру, можно использовать:

```
(Math.round(12563 / 100) * 100)
```

Но код на странице выглядит следующим образом:

```
<div class="shop-item-price">
    <span class="id-good-455-price">15146 грн.</span>
</div>

<div class="shop-item-price">
    <span class="id-good-325-price">12563 грн.</span> 

    <span class="oldprice">
        <span class="id-good-325-old-price">13213 грн.</span>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="price">
    <span class="id-good-455-price">15146 грн.</span>
</div>
```

То есть внутри тега находится еще и текст. Можно ли без изменения HTML-кода пройтись по всем тегам и округлить цифры в большую или меньшую сторону? Премного благодарен за примеры или описание процесса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию **[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)**, чтобы округлить число:

```js
var price = "15146 грн.";
price = (Math.round(parseInt(price, 10) / 100) * 100);

console.log(price);
```

Чтобы пройтись по всем тегам, используйте селектор `$(select)`. Например, если у вас имеется несколько `<span>` с классом `price`:

```
$('span.price').each(function() {
    price = $(this).text();
    price = (Math.round(parseInt(price, 10) / 100) * 100);
    ...
});
```

**[Живой пример на codepen.io](https://codepen.io/phen0menon/pen/XRYWjB)**

Comment: Спасибо, а как можно привязаться к классу который начинается с `id-good-`? В таблице стилей можно использовать селектор, но в JS такой способ не работает? Есть ли аналог этому?

Comment: И пример лучше добавьте с [кодом из вопроса](https://codepen.io/pen/VbdZNR), для многих будет полезно.

Comment: phen0men я так понимаю вы jQuery использовали для получения className?

Comment: Да, библиотека подключена на сайте, поэтому, почему бы и нет? А так в примере можно и на чистом JS сделать. Пока не могу зацепить все теги. Если просто к span привязаться, то на наличии вложенных span-ов это поле будет пустым.

Comment: Вы все же добавили класс в теги, чего я сделать не смогу, но, все равно помогли решить задачу. Я выставлю ответ со своим кодом, а ваше решение отмечу как правильное.

Comment: Хотя, не буду добавлять, кому нужно и сами разберутся как пройтись по тегам)

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev если не секрет, то почему последний `<div>` имеет иной класс? Если бы все `<div>`, в которых указана цена, имели один общий класс, тогда можно было бы не добавлять класс `price` к `<span>`, а сделать так: `$( '.shop-item-price span' ).each(function() { ... });`

Comment: Это дивы из разных страниц, поэтому и классы разные. Внутренние span-ы генерирует система. Тут вопрос в том. что если в span вложен еще один спан, то получим NaN. В этом и был мой вопрос. Можете посмотреть по ссылке из второго комментария на готовое решение.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev `NaN` получим, если использовать `.html()`. Эта функция получает значение первого элемента в наборе. Замените `.html()` на `.text()`.

[ссылка на codepen](https://codepen.io/phen0menon/pen/EmRxeJ)

Comment: О, спасибо. Про `.text()` и не подумал)

Answer (score 1):

Мое решение без `jQuery`:

```
let id_good_455 = document.querySelector('.id-good-455-price').innerHTML; // получаем содержимое тега
id_good_455 = (Math.round(parseInt(id_good_455, 10) / 100) * 100);

console.log(id_good_455);
```

Comment: А как же id-good-325-price и id-good-325-old-price ?

Comment: для каждого элемента нужна своя переменная, привел решение на нативном js